# How to synchronise data between OpenLdap and Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, openldap, data-synchronization

Currently I have a OpenLDAP database used by all the services (emai, svn ..) and i would like to synchronise it with an ActiveDirectory (AD).

I've done some research and i found that it could be done using 389DS (Open Source LDAP developed by Redhat) but to do so I have to migrate my own database to 389DS which I prefer not to do for the moment.

So I am asking for your help. If you have any idea, please be my guess !

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enjoy it http://lsc-project.org/wiki/

you should be happy to have it

Jacko